# Before after HTML/CSS (not image) comparison

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

There are plenty before/after image comparison scripts available on the web (i.e. [here](http://thenewcode.com/819/A-Before-And-After-Image-Comparison-Slide-Control-in-HTML5)) however, I am looking whether it would be possible to use similar slider concept to compare 2 pieces of HTML?

Let's say that I want to present user how certain CSS will affect certain element (i.e. div or table) and use slider so that user could play with it exactly the same way as it works in link I provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if I understood your question correctly, you want to replace the images in the slider with HTML content, right?

Modifying the code from http://lea.verou.me/2014/07/image-comparison-slider-with-pure-css/:

HTML

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="styled"><div class="content">

        <!-- your html content goes here -->

    </div></div>
    <div class="original">

        <!-- repeat your html content here -->

    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {background:white; font:12px/150% tahoma; width:100%; height:100%; position:relative;}

#main {
    position:relative;
    display: block;
    width:60%;
    height:60%;
}

/* styling the styled html */

#main > div.styled {
    /* these are the important parts */
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
    width: 25px; /* you can change this */
    max-width:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    height:100%;
    resize: horizontal;

    /* the below are the styles you want to preview */
    background:#000;
    color:#fff;
}

#main div.styled > div.content {width:100%;}

/* styling the resize drag thingy */

#main > div.styled::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    right: 0; bottom: 0;
    width: 13px; height: 13px;
    padding: 5px;
    background: linear-gradient(-45deg, white 50%, transparent 0);
    background-clip: content-box;
    cursor: ew-resize;
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0 0 2px black);
    filter: drop-shadow(0 0 2px black);
}

/* original HTML w/out styling div */

#main .original {
    user-select: none;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Because this code is for a responsive slider (I set the #main as 60% width and 60% height), we have to set the width of the inner .content dynamically with jQuery such that it's equal to the width of the .original div so that the content doesn't break halfway and instead flows from left to right while we're hiding the overflow of its parent. So:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var styleWidth = $(".original").width();
    $(".content").css("width", function(){
        return styleWidth;
    });
});
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/73rr7yog/5/

If you want to have padding on the .original and .styled, I would recommend setting them to be the same value for the "seamless" effect that the image slider has.

You can also have the slider slide vertically, like in the jsFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/73rr7yog/6/ 
if you just change `resize:horizontal` to `resize:vertical;` and have `width:100%; max-height:100%; height:25px;` for the .styled div

I hope this helps you out

Answer (score 0):

Similar question were asked about how you can disable all styles. This was the code suggested:

```
.reset-this {
animation : none;
animation-delay : 0;
animation-direction : normal;
animation-duration : 0;
animation-fill-mode : none;
animation-iteration-count : 1;
animation-name : none;
animation-play-state : running;
animation-timing-function : ease;
backface-visibility : visible;
background : 0;
background-attachment : scroll;
background-clip : border-box;
background-color : transparent;
background-image : none;
background-origin : padding-box;
background-position : 0 0;
background-position-x : 0;
background-position-y : 0;
background-repeat : repeat;
background-size : auto auto;
border : 0;
border-style : none;
border-width : medium;
border-color : inherit;
border-bottom : 0;
border-bottom-color : inherit;
border-bottom-left-radius : 0;
border-bottom-right-radius : 0;
border-bottom-style : none;
border-bottom-width : medium;
border-collapse : separate;
border-image : none;
border-left : 0;
border-left-color : inherit;
border-left-style : none;
border-left-width : medium;
border-radius : 0;
border-right : 0;
border-right-color : inherit;
border-right-style : none;
border-right-width : medium;
border-spacing : 0;
border-top : 0;
border-top-color : inherit;
border-top-left-radius : 0;
border-top-right-radius : 0;
border-top-style : none;
border-top-width : medium;
bottom : auto;
box-shadow : none;
box-sizing : content-box;
caption-side : top;
clear : none;
clip : auto;
color : inherit;
columns : auto;
column-count : auto;
column-fill : balance;
column-gap : normal;
column-rule : medium none currentColor;
column-rule-color : currentColor;
column-rule-style : none;
column-rule-width : none;
column-span : 1;
column-width : auto;
content : normal;
counter-increment : none;
counter-reset : none;
cursor : auto;
direction : ltr;
display : inline;
empty-cells : show;
float : none;
font : normal;
font-family : inherit;
font-size : medium;
font-style : normal;
font-variant : normal;
font-weight : normal;
height : auto;
hyphens : none;
left : auto;
letter-spacing : normal;
line-height : normal;
list-style : none;
list-style-image : none;
list-style-position : outside;
list-style-type : disc;
margin : 0;
margin-bottom : 0;
margin-left : 0;
margin-right : 0;
margin-top : 0;
max-height : none;
max-width : none;
min-height : 0;
min-width : 0;
opacity : 1;
orphans : 0;
outline : 0;
outline-color : invert;
outline-style : none;
outline-width : medium;
overflow : visible;
overflow-x : visible;
overflow-y : visible;
padding : 0;
padding-bottom : 0;
padding-left : 0;
padding-right : 0;
padding-top : 0;
page-break-after : auto;
page-break-before : auto;
page-break-inside : auto;
perspective : none;
perspective-origin : 50% 50%;
position : static;
/* May need to alter quotes for different locales (e.g fr) */
quotes : '\201C' '\201D' '\2018' '\2019';
right : auto;
tab-size : 8;
table-layout : auto;
text-align : inherit;
text-align-last : auto;
text-decoration : none;
text-decoration-color : inherit;
text-decoration-line : none;
text-decoration-style : solid;
text-indent : 0;
text-shadow : none;
text-transform : none;
top : auto;
transform : none;
transform-style : flat;
transition : none;
transition-delay : 0s;
transition-duration : 0s;
transition-property : none;
transition-timing-function : ease;
unicode-bidi : normal;
vertical-align : baseline;
visibility : visible;
white-space : normal;
widows : 0;
width : auto;
word-spacing : normal;
z-index : auto;
}
```

You can replace it with the piece of code in the link

Actually I can see that they did implement the feature you want:

http://lea.verou.me/2014/07/image-comparison-slider-with-pure-css/

Comment: I am afraid you didn't understand I do not want **image** comparison - I want to compare HTML with and without CSS using slider